# Modular iOS Swift Architecture

Tags: ios, swift, clean-architecture

Im trying to learn and master modular architecture on iOS development, I've found a lot of resources that explain this but it seems like each developer took this topic differently, does anyone knows a course or book where this techniques are standard? or a more accepted and professional solution?

I really want to learn about sharing resources like localizable strings, colors, images between modules or custom frameworks, how to make "templates" for reusable views and instance them on the main app project, build them for getting better build times on main app, test this modules etc.

I now my request is very large, but I ended up with too many information with different implementations so I'm wondering if there's any one book or course solution, or even a learning path to stick with it and complete this. My apologizes if this is not the right place to do this kind of questions. Hope you can help or "guide" me with this. Thanks!

Comment: ON your journey, Be careful not to fall in to one of the "religions" of architecture!

Comment: Honestly, there are no *standards* except for Apple's. While there *are* resources for *...localizable strings, colors, images between modules or custom frameworks..."*, without more specifics - for instance, making a template for reusable views... do you mean an Xcode template or a XIB, or a UIView class as your base view? Without ore specifics, it's hard to help you. Without more? I'd suggest starting with the basics - Apple Developer, their HIG, and finding a specific resource (based on your tags I'd start with the first two, Swift and iOS) through Google.

Comment: @dfd can you please suggest general starter course?

Answer (score 0):

I was searching about this lately, regarding the architecture you may need to know about Clean Architecture principles in general not a specific implementation, you will find a lot of implementations with different thought and maybe most of them are right in the case of the their apps

I think the best resource to understand the concept is Uncle Bob Lecture about [Principle of Clean Architecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_TH-Y78tt4)

After understanding it, you will have a visualization about what you need to do, how to separate components, how you handle dependencies, how each component deals with the others and how to divide component in different layers like Domain, Data, Presentation, ...

After that you may try to implement your thoughts in an application, and you can use any architecture for the presentation ( MVVM , VIP "CleanSwift")

Also if you want to take a look on this [Simple Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbqO6.png)
this is an implementation for the Clean Architecture using MVVM, you can find that Domain is independent, and this is how it should be, so we can plug and unplug any kind of data and presentation on the app business domain, also data here can be replaced easily, also the presentation, if you want for example to change the MVVM to use VIP, the domain will not be touched and presentation layer can be changed easily.

Also note that you will need to use dependency injection, using dependency injection in the communication is very important to help in making components loosely coupled and testable as well

Finally the goal here is to make things not coupled and pluggable, whatever architecture you use, you need to separate components to be used as plugins.

Also this is a very good article about this topic: [medium](https://tech.olx.com/clean-architecture-and-mvvm-on-ios-c9d167d9f5b3)

I Hope I Helped!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to split your application into independent modules in order to be able to reuse them and make your project lighter, more developer friendly and decrease a compile time. It's a great approach especially if you want to build a scalable application. Right now I'm working on something like that. I'm building a development approach - Composable Mobile that brings this modular project structure into a standard. You can read more about that here http://braincode.xyz/ and here https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-composable-architecture. The swift-composable-architecture is a glue we use in our approach to standardize all modules interfaces. I'm very interested to hear what do you think about it